# Client Side Editor

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to make client side editor such that both the sections i.e code section and output section are on the same page. Also when we do editing in the coding section it shows the output in the output section as soon as we click the run button.

PFA
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI609.png)

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress i don't know and think not exist.. but you can use the page builder plugin so Themify Builder, Elementor, Beaver Builder.
Or you can use the code editor in theme -> eidtor  exist also the plugin for advanced editor.